# Tkinter looks different on different computers

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinter window looks very different on different computers (running on the same resolution!):

windows 8
[image: windows 8]

windows 7
[image: windows 7]

I want it to look like it does in the first one. Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```
class Application():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Tk()
        self.app.wm_iconbitmap('.\data\spider.ico')
        self.app.wm_title("Spider Crawler")
        self.app.minsize(width=914, height=331)
        self.app.maxsize(width=914, height=331)

        mainmainleft = Frame(self.app)
        bottom = Frame(self.app)

        mainleft = Frame(mainmainleft)
        itemoptions = Frame(bottom)
        self.graph = multilist.McListBox(bottom)

        startn = Frame(mainleft)
        options = Frame(mainleft)
        hourcredits = Frame(mainleft)

        hoursoption = Frame(hourcredits)
        credits = Frame(hourcredits)

        allbuttons = Frame(mainleft)

        fstart = Frame(startn)

        bp = Frame(allbuttons)
        buttons = Frame(allbuttons)

        self.SchemaUpdate = BooleanVar()
        self.reset = BooleanVar()
        self.genuine = BooleanVar()
        self.buds = BooleanVar()
        self.bills = BooleanVar()
        self.unusual = BooleanVar()
        self.maxs = BooleanVar()
        self.bmoc = BooleanVar()
        self.salvage = BooleanVar()
        self.traded = BooleanVar()
        self.entryid = StringVar()

        self.clicked = False

        for i in [self.reset, self.buds, self.unusual, self.maxs, self.salvage]:
            i.set(True)

        self.b = Button(fstart, text="START", command=self.start)
        c = Button(buttons, text="Steam", command=self.steam).pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,7))
        d = Button(buttons, text="GotoBP", command=self.backpack).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.b.pack(side=LEFT)

        buttons.pack()
        self.var = StringVar(self.app)
        self.var.set("backpack.tf/profiles/")

        option = OptionMenu(bp, self.var, "backpack.tf/profiles/", "tf2items.com/profiles/", "tf2b.com/tf2/")
        option.config(width = 18)
        option.pack()
        bp.pack(side = BOTTOM)    

        self.box = Entry(startn, textvariable=self.entryid, fg = "gray")
        self.box.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        self.box.insert(0, "Enter steamid")
        self.box.pack(side = TOP, anchor=N, padx =(5,25), pady = 10)

        Label(credits, text="Created by Akenne", font=("Times New Roman", 8)).pack(anchor = E, pady = (0,25))

        credits.pack(side=TOP, anchor=E)

        Label(hoursoption, text="Max Hours:").pack(side=LEFT, padx = (0,10))

        self.hours=IntVar()
        self.hours.set(250)
        Entry(hoursoption,textvariable=self.hours,width=5).pack(side=LEFT)

        hoursoption.pack(padx= (0,45))

        Checkbutton(options, text = "Reload item schema", variable = self.SchemaUpdate).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, pady =(0, 3))
        Checkbutton(options, text = "Start with fresh id", variable = self.reset).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Only never traded items", variable = self.traded).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Genuines", variable = self.genuine).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Earbuds", variable = self.buds).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Bill's", variable = self.bills).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Unusuals", variable = self.unusual).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Max's items", variable = self.maxs).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "BMOCs", variable = self.bmoc).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        Checkbutton(itemoptions, text = "Salvaged crates", variable = self.salvage).pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
        self.lbl = Label(fstart, text="0/0 found")
        self.lbl.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = W, padx = (20,30))

        fstart.pack(side=TOP)

        startn.pack(side=LEFT, anchor = W, padx = (10, 0))
        options.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,30), pady = (5,0))
        allbuttons.pack(side=LEFT, pady=(10,0), padx = (40,0))
        hourcredits.pack(side=LEFT, padx = (95,0), anchor = E)

        mainleft.pack(side = TOP, anchor = W)
        self.graph.container.pack(side = LEFT, anchor = W, pady = 10)
        itemoptions.pack(side=LEFT, anchor = E, padx=7)

        mainmainleft.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)
        bottom.pack(padx =10)
        self.app.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's just the way it is. Most folks consider it looking like the underlying GUI a good thing.

Comment: What, exactly, about the first one do you want to duplicate for the second one? The placement of the `Created by` and `Max hours` elements?

Comment: Not just that but I don't want the excessive white space around the edges on the second one.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, tkinter applications will look different on different platforms. This is by design. When possible, Tkinter will use native widgets -- widgets provided by the OS. This means that Tkinter does not have ultimate control over every aspect of the GUI.

Under most circumstances this is the desired behavior. You want a button on Windows to look like a Windows button, and you want a button on OSX to look like an OSX button. This also means that you may get different buttons on Windows 7 vs Windows 8 -- tkinter is just using whatever the OS gives it, and Microsoft tends to tweak its widgets with every major revision.

Can you get the exact same look on all platforms? That depends. You can probably get nearly identical results on Windows 7 and 8 with a small amount of work. It will be very difficult to get the same look between Windows and Macintosh.

Unfortunately, these differences not only result in different looking widgets, but it can cause layout differences as well. For example, different platforms may have different fonts, different default border widths, and default margins and padding. All of this contributes to the final layout of a window.

In your specific case, the most obvious difference is that Windows 7 is using a slightly smaller font than Windows 8. That alone can have a big effect on layout. It also appears that the McListBox widget has a larger border around it on windows 7 than on windows 8. I don't know anything about that widget, so it could have different defaults based on the platform.

Most of these problems can be resolved by using explicit values for borders, padding, fonts, etc. Sometimes it takes a little experimentation.

Answer (score 3):

### Is it possible?

While it seems as a natural wish, the target is not possible due to many reasons in Tk/Tcl reliance on localhost O/S windowing manager services. Here it starts. { MacOS, Linux OS, W* OS }-WM-s definitely do similar tasks, however, not with a same look-and-feel.

Simplest seen on rather different results of the `.pack()` Geometry Manager outputs on row two with just a few trivial `Button()`-s there

The closest hit may be to use "Tk Themed Widget" library, a.k.a. **`ttk`**

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

With `ttk` you construct GUI-s with `ttk.`<*Widgets*>, 11 of which already existed in Tkinter: ttk.Button, ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Entry, ttk.Frame, ttk.Label, ttk.LabelFrame, ttk.Menubutton, ttk.PanedWindow, ttk.Radiobutton, ttk.Scale and ttk.Scrollbar plus some new widget classes are added - Combobox, Notebook, Progressbar, Separator, Sizegrip and Treeview -- all of which comfortly "subclass" from Widget.

Key issue is the **theme-ing**

The **look-and-feel** as well as the styling code ( + ttk style-configuration efforts ) tries to help achieve a better cross-platform UI appearance.

While **this brings you a way closer**, it is not easy to have identical look-an-feel both on X11-terminal and W7.

Comment: This answer seems to ignore the fact that OP using windows on both systems?? I can understand difference between macos, Linux, Windows, but W7 vs W8??

Comment: @Brandin: Obviously **not ignoring**, sir. The W7 WM is by far different from the W8 one. Even of it were possible to "enforce" to have identical WM-services ( not only the visible differences  `Tkinter.Tk()` and `Tkinter.Toplevel()` "outer-framing" widgets, but trully the identical WM-services top-to-bottom implementation ) handling as W7, or wXP, or wNT, or w3.11, this particular case would not be a solution for the given OP. Just realise further differences in `aWidget["font"]`-s, `.iconbitmap()`-s, `aWidget["cursor"]`-s, even in `<MouseWheel>` handling. **Identical look-&-feel is problem**

Comment: Your answer is confusing -- you write "Simplest seen on rather different results of the `.pack()` Geometry Manager...". `pack` gives exactly the same results on all platforms. Maybe you meant to say that you get different results from the `Button` command?

Comment: @BryanOakley **Not at all, sir**. I respect your indepth knowledge. So, if you kindly spend a bit more seconds on reading into details, you would sure notice, that **the very `.pack(anchor = E, pady = (0,25))` has produced a different looking results** for `Label( credits, ...` in { w7 | w8 } environments.

Comment: @user3666197: I think you're confusing what the packer does and what a Label does. All the packer does is decide _where_ a widget goes. It has absolutely no effect on what it looks like. If a widget ends up in a different place, it's not because of platform differences in pack, it's because of platform differences in the widget (different sized fonts, borders, etc).

Comment: @BryanOakley Excuse me, sir, you have missed the chance. No theory, just view the facts above, in the OP. If you were a bit more carefull & checked the OP source code, **there is no other reason for the difference** in the look-&-feel observed in posted { w7 | w8 }, is it? **( And known & common "differences" in font metrics will not make those 3 in. difference in screen layout, would they? )** Please, excuse me to stop responding on this subject, as it does not bring any new value to the OP & it would just waste your intensive & genuine support for StackOverflow community.

Comment: @user3666197: you ask " there is no other reason for the difference in the look-&-feel observed in posted { w7 | w8 }, is it?". Yes, there are other reasons. The reason is _not_ that pack is platform-dependent, it's because the data fed into pack is different. This is an important distinction. Pack does absolutely the same thing on all platforms, but different platforms have different defaults with respect to margins, padding, font sizes, etc.