# Fixing the positions of widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a gui using Tkinter and when i send that code to my friend to further work on, the places of buttons and other widgets get distorted.Is there a way by which i can assure that whatever OS he is using, it will show the same result as it shows on my system.

My friend is using mac and i'm working on windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter looks different on different computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354160/tkinter-looks-different-on-different-computers)

Comment: Without code we can't help you. In general, as long as you're using `grid` or `pack` properly, everything will be aligned correctly no matter what the OS, screen resolution, or fonts the app uses.