# Tkinter interface looking different / not working from wsl

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I´ve been building an interface in tkinter and because of other modules I need to run it in Ubuntu from now on. The thing is, I know it's supposed to look different, but when I run it in wsl it pretty much stops working. Any reason why this is happening? I'm calling python from wsl. Any help would be really appreciated. [Original GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxT9m.jpg) [GUI from Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0jqW.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter looks different on different computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354160/tkinter-looks-different-on-different-computers)

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from tkinter. What other libraries are you using? Are they all multiplatform?

Comment: Besides tkinter, im using matplotlib, PIL and opencv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.